# Cookie names must not be empty (Login Case)

Tags: php, json

Hello guys I want to login and I have a problem. A condition is that Cookie names must not be empty (Login Case). This is my code

```
$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/sid/services/view/Accounts.php');
$jsonData = array( 'USERNAME' => $username, 'PASSWORD' => $password );
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$sess_arr = json_decode($result, true);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($ch);
var_dump($sess_arr);
echo'</pre>';

if(isset($sess_arr['errorMessages'][0])) { 
echo $sess_arr['errorMessages'][0];
}   
else {
setcookie($sess_arr['ROLE_ID']['ROLE_ID'], $sess_arr['ROLE_ID']['USERNAME'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo "Login Success!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcookie` needs to call before any output ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)). please remove or comment out the following code.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($ch);
var_dump($sess_arr);
echo'</pre>';
```

In addition, you might need to change your code as below as far as I saw `var_dump($sess_arr);` output.

```
foreach ($sess_arr as $sess) {
    setcookie($sess['ROLE_ID'], $sess['USERNAME'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

Comment: its code want test to display value. my error 
Notice: Undefined index: USERNAME in C:\xampp\htdocs\sid\index\proses.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: ROLE_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\sid\index\proses.php on line 31
Warning: Cookie names must not be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\sid\index\proses.php on line 31
Login Success!

Comment: this is my result var_dump($sess_arr);  array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["USERNAME"]=> string(23) "firmanbrilian@gmail.com" ["NAME"]=> string(14) "Firman Brilian" ["PASSWORD"]=> string(32) "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b" ["EMAIL"]=> string(23) "firmanbrilian@gmail.com" ["ROLE_ID"]=> int(2) } [1]=> array(5) { ["USERNAME"]=> string(24) "firmanbriliant@gmail.com" ["NAME"]=> string(4) "Beni" ["PASSWORD"]=> string(32) "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b" ["EMAIL"]=> string(24) "firmanbriliant@gmail.com" ["ROLE_ID"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: if username has multiple role id,  do you want to set multiple cookies?

Comment: i want create cookies USERNAME and ROLE_ID

Comment: maybe there are different things to your request, updated my answer.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear that. could you choose my answer as a good answer?

Comment: sure maybe you can wait 15 minutes